# select()ed socket fails to to recv() complete data

Tags: c, sockets

With the following pseudo-Python script for sending data to a local socket:

```
s = socket.socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect("./sock.sock")
s.send("test\n")
s.send("aaa\0")
s.close()
```

My C program will randomly end up `recv`ing the following buffers:

- `test\n`
- `test\n<random chars>`
- `test\naaa` (as expected)

The socket is being `recv()`'d after `select()` points that the socket is readable. Question is, how to avoid the first two cases?

And side question: Is it possible to send the following two messages from that script:

- `asd\0`
- `dsa\0`

And have `select()` to show the socket as readable on each of those `send`s, or will it only do that if I run the script again (restarting the socket client `connect`ion) and sending a message for each `connect`?

Comment: Could you copy the snippet with the recv line for us? I guess you are not paying attention how many bytes you receive and you don't receive repeatedly... but it's only a guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a guess, the `len` argument to [recv](http://linux.die.net/man/2/recv) specifies a maximum amount of data to read, not the precise amount to be returned.  `recv` is free to return any amount of data *up to* `len` bytes instead.

If you want to read a specific number of bytes, call `recv` in a loop.

```
 int bytes = 0;
 while (bytes < len) {
    int remaining = len - bytes;
    int read = recv(sockfd, buf+bytes, remaining, 0);
    if (read < 0) {
        // error
        break;
    }
    bytes += read;
 }
```

As noted by junix, if you'll need to send unpredictable amounts of data, consider defining a simple protocol that either starts each message with a note of its length or ends with a particular byte or sequence of bytes.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that @Matoe should think about a proper protocol definition to send his data like (\n as frame delimiter or something) as data can be chunked however the TCP/IP stack likes to chunk it.

Comment: I'd missed the second question before.  I'm afraid I'm not sure I understand it now.  In case it helps, you can call send as often as you like on a connected socket.  All the data will be delivered to the server.  If you close the client socket, you'll have to call connect again before further sends.